# I need a formula for fading image based on scroll

Tags: javascript, html

Currently, I’m using the following formula:

```
var scrollTop = $(this).scrollTop();
$('.item').css({opacity: 100 / scrollTop});
```

But if you watch on the home page of my website, its stops fading at one moment,

Someone please guide me better formula

[My website](https://www.mystem.tk)

Comment: Use CSS Transitions.

Comment: Try this: https://codepen.io/nickcil/pen/sfutl/

Comment: @Amy CSS won't take the offset of the page into account of setting the opacity.

Comment: i changed the / 250 to / 650 and that works perfect, thanks mikaal

Comment: ill need to wait 4 more minutes to be able to approve your answer, but i have upvoted it

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should try this:

```
$(window).scroll(function(){
    $(".top").css("opacity", 1 - $(window).scrollTop() / 250);
  });
```

Source: https://codepen.io/nickcil/pen/sfutl/

Answer (score 1):

I've used this JS code to achieve what I believe you're trying to do here, before on a couple of sites I've built:

```
$(window).scroll(function(){ // standard JS document open 
    $(".top_section").css("opacity", 1 - 
        $(window).scrollTop() / 260); // set where you want fade to begin  

});
```